# Reference number about a Hadith making gold permissible for women

Tags: hadith-interpretation, source-identification

> It was narrated in Sunan Abi Dawood with a saheeh isnaad from
> ‘Aa’ishah (may Allaah be pleased with her) that she said: “Some
> jewellery came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon
> him) as a gift from the Negus (the ruler of Abyssinia), as a gift to
> him. It included a gold ring in which was set an Abyssinian stone. The
> Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) picked
> it up hesitantly with a stick or with his fingers, then he called
> Umaamah the daughter of Abu’l-‘Aas and his daughter Zaynab. He said,
> ‘Adorn yourself with this, O my daughter.’” The Prophet (peace and
> blessings of Allaah be upon him) gave a ring to Umaamah, which was
> formed from a circle of gold, and said, “Adorn yourself with this."

[Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/11886)

In my country some sheikh saying wearing gold is also forbidden for women. So I need this Hadith for proof. But the problem is I can't find the reference number. Please help me to find it.

Comment: A hadith number depends on the printed edition not on the original text. So it is basically variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hadith can be found in Sunan Abi Dawud in the book كتاب الخاتم under the section باب ما جاء في الذهب للنساء . The number will vary with the publisher, however it is numbered 4235 in the English translation [published by Darussalam](https://muslim-library.com/books/en_English_Translation_of_Sunan_Abu_Dawud_Volume4.pdf#page=480).

> حدثنا ابن نفيل، حدثنا محمد بن سلمة، عن محمد بن إسحاق، قال: حدثني يحيى بن عباد، عن أبيه، عباد بن عبد الله، عن عائشة رضي الله عنها، قالت: قدمت على النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم حلية من عند النجاشي، أهداها له، فيها خاتم من ذهب فيه فص حبشي، قالت: فأخذه رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بعود معرضا عنه - أو ببعض أصابعه - ثم دعا أمامة ابنة أبي العاص، ابنة ابنته زينب، فقال: تحلي بهذا يا بنية
>
> <sup>— [Sunan Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/36/22)</sup>